# Disable Dynamic Links using Javascript

Tags: jquery

I have some dynamic links that are generated via an e-commerce plugin. They have a unique id. I was wondering if it is possible to disable a link via jQuery or Javascript?

Comment: can you show some sample links generated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this script sets the attribute of all anchor items to '#' (you will need to provide logic to determine if it's a link you want to modify):

```
$("a").each(function(index, item) {
  $(item).attr("href", "#");
});
```

if the anchor tags in your document have a common class, you could select them all by class name instead:

```
$(".e-commerce-links").each(// same as above
```

another option is to remove the `href` attribute altogether

```
$("a").each(function(index, item) {
  $(item).removeAttr("href");
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I managed to figure out the problem before stock-overflow notified me of the answer. But I appreciate your help!